# ¿Por qué me sale este error? - Type error: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python

Cuando corro el código me da este error. ¿Dónde está el error en mi código? Me dice que el error se encuentra en: `numero < adivinar`.

```
intentos = 0
max_intentos = intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad -1]

adivinar = int(input())
print(f'Es tu momento jugador 2, tienes {intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad-1]} intentos para adivinar el numero elegido por el jugador 1. Iremos dandote pistas de si el numero buscado es mayor o menor. A POR ELLO!')

numero = int(input())
while intentos < max_intentos:
     if numero == adivinar:
         print('ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO!')

     if numero < adivinar:
         print('El número que buscas en mayor')

      else:
         print('El número que buscas es menor')
```

Comment: please change the question to spanish

Comment: El error te dice estás comparando un string str con un entero int.  Podrias probar con  una conversion cast. Revisar los tipos que da a la variables. No soy muy de python pero esta es la ayuda que puedo dar. Yo usaba raw_input en su momento.

Comment: El error dice que no puedes comparar un entero con una cadena. Ya que la comparación es `intentos < max_intentos` y por el código se ve que `intentos` es un entero (pues haces `int()` sobre el valor devuelto por `input()`) se deduce entonces que `max_intentos` ha de ser una cadena. Revisa cómo obtienes la lista `intentos_dificultad`. Sospercho que la leas de un fichero.

Comment: @yors te quedaste en Python 2. ahora, input hace lo que hacía raw_input y raw_input fue eliminado. Por lo demás, estás en lo cierto.

Comment: @YORS. `raw_input` está obsoleto hace años.

Comment: El segundo `if` debería ser un `elif`. De lo contrario tienes dos `if` en secuencia.

Answer (score 0):

El error que está recibiendo se produce porque está intentando comparar un número entero (int) con una cadena de caracteres (str). En su código, está intentando comparar el número ingresado por el usuario (adivinar) con la cantidad de intentos permitidos (max_intentos), pero el valor de max_intentos es una cadena de caracteres en lugar de un número entero.

Para solucionar este error, deberá convertir el valor de max_intentos a un número entero antes de intentar compararlo con adivinar. Puede hacer esto utilizando la función int() de Python, que convierte una cadena de caracteres en un número entero.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo modificar su código para evitar este error:

```
intentos = 0
max_intentos = intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad -1]

adivinar = int(input())
print(f'Es tu momento jugador 2, tienes {intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad-1]} intentos para adivinar el numero elegido por el jugador 1. Iremos dandote pistas de si el numero buscado es mayor o menor. A POR ELLO!')

numero = int(input())
while intentos < int(max_intentos):  # Convert max_intentos to an int before comparing
     if numero == adivinar:
         print('ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO!')

     if numero < adivinar:
         print('El número que buscas en mayor')

      else:
         print('El número que buscas es menor')
```

En este ejemplo, hemos agregado una llamada a la función int() dentro del bucle while para convertir el valor de max_intentos a un número entero antes de compararlo con adivinar. De esta manera, el código debería funcionar correctamente sin producir el error que estaba recibiendo.

También es importante asegurarse de que el valor de max_intentos es una cadena de caracteres que represente un número entero válido. Si el valor de max_intentos contiene algún carácter que no sea un dígito (por ejemplo, un signo de puntuación o un espacio), la función int() producirá un error al intentar convertirlo en un número entero. En este caso, deberá asegurarse de eliminar cualquier carácter no deseado del valor de max_intentos antes de intentar convertirlo a un número entero.

También puedes optimizar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
adivinar = int(input())
print(f'Es tu momento jugador 2, tienes {intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad-1]} intentos para adivinar el numero elegido por el jugador 1. Iremos dandote pistas de si el numero buscado es mayor o menor. A POR ELLO!')

while True:  # Simplified while loop using break statement
    numero = int(input())
    if numero == adivinar:
        print('ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO!')
        break
    elif numero < adivinar:
        print('El número que buscas en mayor')
    else:
        print('El número que buscas es menor')
```

En este ejemplo, el bucle while se ha simplificado utilizando la sentencia break para terminar el bucle cuando se cumpla la condición de que el número ingresado por el usuario sea igual al número que se está buscando. De esta manera, se puede evitar el uso de la variable de control de bucle intentos y la condición de finalización del bucle intentos < max_intentos, lo que simplifica el código y lo hace más legible.

Otra forma de optimizar el código es utilizar el operador ternario de Python para simplificar la lógica de la comparación entre el número ingresado por el usuario y el número que se está buscando. En lugar de utilizar una estructura de control de flujo if-else para determinar si el número es mayor, menor o igual al número que se está buscando, se puede utilizar un operador ternario para evaluar esta lógica en una sola expresión:

```
adivinar = int(input())
print(f'Es tu momento jugador 2, tienes {intentos_dificultad[respuesta_dificultad-1]} intentos para adivinar el numero elegido por el jugador 1. Iremos dandote pistas de si el numero buscado es mayor o menor. A POR ELLO!')

while True:
    numero = int(input())
    # Use a ternary operator to evaluate comparison
    resultado = 'El número que buscas en mayor' if numero < adivinar else 'El número que buscas es menor'
    if numero == adivinar:
        print('ENHORABUENA, HAS ACERTADO!')
        break
    else:
        print(resultado)
```

En este ejemplo, el operador ternario se encuentra en la línea 8, donde se evalúa si el número ingresado por el usuario es menor que el número que se está buscando. Si esta condición se cumple, la expresión devuelve la cadena 'El número que buscas en mayor', y si la condición no se cumple, devuelve la cadena 'El número que buscas es menor'.

Espero que esto le ayude a entender cómo se utiliza un operador ternario para simplificar la lógica de comparación en su código. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias!